# How to keep saves automatically without import/export?

Tags: a-dark-room

I wanna keep my game saved and opened automaticaly, without import or export is there a way to achive this?

Comment: There is a way, but export to create a backup. Also, if using incognito browsing (or private) it can't autosave, so export it.

Answer (score 2):

A dark room uses an autosave feature. It will save your game every 10 seconds I believe it was. [Mentioning of autosave](http://forum.rpg.net/showthread.php?692764-Browsergames-A-Dark-Room/page3), [and one more.](http://www.therainbowhub.com/game-review-a-dark-room/)

When saved, it shows in the top right corner. Keep an eye on that to know when your progress has been saved.

Comment: It actually saves the game every 1 minute.